# onclick="function()" not working but href="javascript: function()" works fine?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a function which quite simply changes the style attributes of an image when clicked.

```
    document.getElementById("normal" + current).setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
```

current is a parameter for the function. e.g. changeImage(10)
and the element image which we want to change the style for has a resultant id of "normal10".

To make it display, basically as it's set as display: none obviously to begin with, we need to change that to block.

So, I have two instances where I call the method changeImage(current).

One which is:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(10);"><img src="xyz"></img></a>
```

and another which is:

```
    <a href="javascript: changeImage(10);"><img src="xyz"></img></a>
```

Both of these function correctly on Chrome & Opera, the display attribute is changed both times.

However on any other browser such as IE or Firefox, the display attribute only seems to get changed where we have

```
    <a href="javascript...">
```

and not where the method is called upon via the onclick.
I tried to change to:

```
    document.getElementById("normal" + current).style.display="block";
```

Unfortunately to no avail.

I don't think there is an issue with the javascript itself. Since the function executes fine when called within the href.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Done with jQuery, code executes but the style of the image still doesn't change. Works in Chrome & Opera still but not in firefox & IE.

I gave the image that is clicked to execute the function an id of "img".

```
    <img id="img" src="..."></img>
```

and the code to execute the function is placed in the following tags (in document ready function):

```
    $('#img').click(function(){}
```

Code is executed, but style is only changed from none to block on specific browsers.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Other than: "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.", Nope. I have console.logs in there to check if code is being executed, and they are.

Comment: Don't mix content(html) with behavior(js). Remove those `onclick` and use jQuery, that takes care for you of those browser differences.

Comment: It would be nice if you used lifelike code in your examples; e.g. `function` as the name of the function is wrong. I don't mean to nitpick, but once you see one thing that you know is not the same as in the real world code you start wondering what else might not be exactly the same. And that's no way to go about solving an "impossible!" problem.

Comment: Can you guys just give me a hint in the right direction with regards to how I can 'use jQuery' to do something like this? I come from a software/Java background and this would be the first time I use jQuery to do something like this. Any pointers in the right direction or examples? Thanks!

Comment: Made changes Jon, cheers.

Comment: @Kyanite Where is your markup? What is your exact code right now? Your last JS snippet has lots of typos.

Comment: I'll fix the markup now, I copy pasted incorrectly. I've also attempted to use jQuery as some have recommended and amended the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a jQuery solution. Here is one:

```
<style>
  /* hide all elements with id starting by normal... */
  [id^=normal] { display: none; }
</style>

<!-- place the http protocol if you are on localhost -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {         // when page is fully loaded

     // define a click event for any
     // anchor with a class "shownormal" and attribute "data-id" defined
     $("a.shownormal[data-id]").click(function (event) {
         $("#normal" + $(this).attr('data-id')).show();
         event.preventDefault();
     });

   });
</script>
```

and your markup can be

```
<a href="#" class="shownormal" data-id="10"><img src="xyz"></img></a>

<a href="#" class="shownormal" data-id="15"><img src="xyz"></img></a>
```

Samples on jsFiddle **[with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/c25g4z36/)** and **[without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/c25g4z36/2/)**

**http://jquery.com/**

Comment: Thanks. However before I resort to your solution, I've changed my function to jQuery. It's working and the function is executed when clicked. However there still seems to be the same problem when the display attribute is changed from none to display, it is only being changed in Chrome + Opera yet not in Firefox & IE. So perhaps changing execution from regular javascrpt to jQuery hasn't added cross browser compatibility?

Comment: "...is changed from none to display" - you made a typo or is this your actual code? Should be "from none to block". If this does not work, then you are doing something else wrong. Changing visibility of elements is a very basic operation and I can guarantee you that jQuery does this correctly across browsers.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my behalf. I completely agree this should be a lot more simpler than it currently seems at the moment and it's baffling me as to why specific browsers aren't functioning. I'll try to play around with it more then try your solution.

Comment: @Kyanite I've added a fiddle to my answer. Please check it. It works in all browsers.

Comment: @Kyanite Added another fiddle in pure JS

Comment: Turned out I was doing everything correctly in fact I had clumsily rushed through writing the original file and made some errors with certain divs. However the examples you gave are perfect solutions to the error I initially thought I had, therefore I will select it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try using this,

```
$("#normal"+current).css("display","block")
```

Comment: It's an `ID`, so in `jQuery`, should be.. `$("#normal"+current)....`... Plus, in OP, there's no [tag:jQuery] TAG

Comment: Changed my function to jQuery. Used what you provided, makes sense. Unfortunately not changing display attributes on any browser. Just seems be making no sense at the moment.